# Laravel 5.1: Handling missing fields in RESTful API

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-middleware

In my Laravel 5.1 application, I have a controller that serves as a RESTful API. Many methods of this controller have a following piece of code:

```
foreach (['email', 'password', 'firstName', 'lastName'] as $parameter) {
    if (!$this->request->has($parameter)) {
        throw new InputException(400, $parameter, 'Missing ' . $parameter . ' parameter.');
    }
}
```

I know it's not the greatest idea to repeat the same piece of code (with different array contents). Instead, I'm looking for some elegant way to achieve the same thing.

I thought about middleware with parameters, something like this in the routes.php:

```
'middleware' => 'parameters:email,password,firstName,lastName'
```

Currently I'm using implicit controllers though, so my methods are not mentioned in `routes.php` file.

What is the most flexible and elegant way to implement this functionality without repeating myself?

Comment: Just because a answer doesnt work out for you, doesn't mean you need to downvote it. Anyway, downvoting ur question too. Good luck

Comment: I downvoted, because your code is just bad and far worse than what I already have.

Comment: By the way, downvoting good question because of butthurt is really pathetic.

Comment: We count a good question by the number of upvotes it has and not the number of downvotes ...

Answer (score 1):

**Laravel's validator** is what you need.

If you have a controller class, you can just add the following in the action method:

```
 $this->validate($this->request, [
    'email' => 'required|email',
    'password' => 'required',
    'firstname' => 'required',
    'lastname' => 'required',
]);
```

This will validate the incoming request and throw **HttpResponseException** if validation rules are not met.

Laravel's Validator is a powerful tool - you can read more about it here: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation

Comment: To whoever is downvoting the answer - I'd love to learn why this solution is not ok :)

Comment: The guy asking the question is the one who is down voting the answers. I'm downvoting his question too

Answer (score 0):

I think, Middleware would be the best option. Middlewares are amazing.
Just create a middleware using `php artisan make:middleware SomeMiddlewareName`

and put this code in its handle function

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{

    $data = array(
        'email' => $request->input('email'),
        'password' => $request->input('password'),
        'firstname' => $request->input('firstname'),
        'lastname' => $request->input('lastname'),
    );

    //Delete array fields that Have null or empty values
    $data = array_filter($data);

    if (sizeof($data) == 4) {
            //Send the user to the required controller
            return $next($request);
    } else {
        //Else, throw whatever error you want to throw
        throw new InputException("Enter all required parameters");
    }
}
```

I think it will work for you.